# How do you manage User Entity / Audit data in CQRS Read Side?

Tags: microservices, cqrs

We have a pretty common situation: Every Aggregate, Command, Event, etc. contains some kind of Audit log: *Who created this? Who did the last modifications? And when?*

And basically every Read Model needs to contain this data, too, because the clients needs to display this information.

---

**For the sake of simplicity, just imagine StackOverflow's Read Model for a Question (including all corresponding Answers and Comments).**

The Read Model contains a lot of Users: Who created the question? Who did the last modifications? And the same data again for every Comment and Answer and the Answer's Comments.

And now think about a bigger platform, with many more Read Models, where basically every Read Model needs the same User information.

---

I now came across 4 different solutions, but I'm not yet sure which one to choose. Or maybe there's even something much better?

1. Only store the `userId` within the Read Model. And the client has to query the `User Service` to get the User names.
2. Self contained microservice (using Events): Each Service stores a mini copy of the User database (only id, name).
3. Coupled microservice: For each request from the client, each Service will query the `User Service` for the User names.
4. Load to whole User database into the client's cache and just use that.

The downsides are:

1. If the `User Service` is unreachable, the client can't display all necessary information. Additionally the client has to extract all `userId`s from the response and make a separate request to the `User Service`.
2. Listening to `UserCreatedEvent`s in order to kinda-copy the whole User database to every microservice is a lot of duplicated code and data.
3. Same problem as with approach 1: If the `User Service` is unreachable, the information can't be displayed. And of course this would introduce high coupling, lot's of network traffic, etc.
4. That's not possible for our current project, because there are far too many Users and new Users can be added frequently.

---

So far *approach 2* looks the best to me, because it should be the most resilient. And the code duplication could be extracted into some `common module` which keeps track of `UserCreatedEvent` and provides some api / callback mechanism.

How did you solve this in your projects? Do you have any other pros / cons?

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to the pros and const that you mentioned I would add some points or questions that you could ask yourself before taking the decision:

> 1. If the User Service is unreachable, the client can't display all necessary information. Additionally the client has to extract all
>      userIds from the response and make a separate request to the User
>      Service.

Is it really bad that for some period the user Information on some screens will not be available? If the User service is down, one of the smallest problems will be that some screens do not have full user information. :)  Also for the client to extract all id's and make a separate call is not so problematic? What could be problematic is the amount of user ids which you want to fetch from 
User Service. It all depends on the amount of records that you are displaying and your use case.

> 2. Listening to UserCreatedEvents in order to kinda-copy the whole User database to every microservice is a lot of duplicated code and
>      data.

In this case it would not be copying the whole User database to each service. From the example that you gave about Stack overflow Questions/Answers it would be a small subset of data like: id and userName. Some kind of Questions List would contain all questions with userId a username who asked the Question. Then if someone wants to see more information about the user he would call User service only in that case. On the other hand not every user asks a question and/or answers question. Still it is a valid point and there is a lot of duplication if you do it in all services. I would say you don't have to use this approach in all services. Only the ones where it fits better and where probably less Users data will be used.

> 3. Same problem as with approach 1: If the User Service is unreachable, the information can't be displayed. And of course this
>      would introduce high coupling, lot's of network traffic, etc.

One additional point for this option compared to 1. option. The fact that the call from External client(WebApp, Mobile app) to some Rest API compared to a local call from one micro-service to another micro-service can be much slower. In general even if the micro-services are not on the same server they are probably on the same Cluster so a call from one to another will be within the same network and therefore faster then a call from some Client application. This is in most cases not much but if you have a lot of calls then it is something you can consider as well.

**General Suggestion**

You should check how each micro-service works with User data and based on that decide to duplicate or call the User micro-service. I would decide it case by case. There are pros and cons to both approaches(Option 1 or Option 2).